# codeigniter pagination for image

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to paginate query results in CodeIgniter to look like this:

[image]

Problem 1 : 
The [Pagination](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/pagination.html) class always outputs numeric links.  I just want to show next and back links.

Problem 2 : 
`$data['links'] = $this->pagination->create_links();` returns all of the links as a string.  How can I separate the next and back links and put next to the right and back to the left ?

Comment: I like codeigniter as php framework, but I do think the pagination from codeigniter is not as good as it should be. I would advise to google for better option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

suppose url is: http://localhost/controller/method/

do following in your controller function

```
...
function method($page_num)
{
  ...
  $data['next_link'] = $page_num + 1;
  $data['prev_link'] = $page_num;
  ...
  $this->load->view('<veiw_name>', $data);

}
```

do this in your view

```
...
<a href="http://localhost/controller/method/<?php echo $prev_link; ?>">Prev</a>
<a href="http://localhost/controller/method/<?php echo $next_link; ?>">Next</a>
....
```

Comment: @Codemaster Snake where the $page_num coming from ?

Comment: I would assume it would be in the URL as variable segment.